# File validation not working when using onsubmit="return validate()" function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

My other validation works fine and if i put an onchange() function on one of the inputs and just put my image file validation then it seems to work but when i paste the same code into the onsubmit="return validate()" function when i press submit with a bad value it just submits the form and goes to the next page.

Im guessing there is an error and i checked the console in chrome but nothing is showing up, im not that good with error handling with javascript so maybe im missing something. Here is my code, the input field verification works fine.

Here is a fiddle but i couldnt get it to work in that so not sure if fiddle is ideal for forms, i have checked this exact code below in a browser and it validates on the 4 input fields but when the too image is not a valid image it just submits. http://jsfiddle.net/FTV5p/4/

```
<form id="fm-form" name="fm-form" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>Personal information</legend>
<label for="fm-username">* Username:</label>
<input name="fm-username" id="fm-username" type="text" />
<label for="fm-email">* Email:</label>
<input id="fm-email" name="fm-email" type="text" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Information</legend>
<label for="fm-tool_name">* Tool Name:</label>
<input id="fm-tool_name" name="fm-tool_name" type="text" />

<label for="fm-tool_desc">* Description:</label>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="fm-tool_desc" name="fm-tool_desc" /></textarea>

  <label for="fm-tool_game_type">* Game Type:</label>
  <select id="fm-tool_game_type" name="fm-tool_game_type">
    <option value="All" selected="selected">All Tool Game Types</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
  </select>

  <label for="fm-tool_table_type">* Table Type:</label>
  <select  id="fm-tool_table_type" name="fm-tool_table_type">
    <option value="All" selected="selected">All Table Types</option>
    <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
    <option value="Round">Round</option>
  </select>

  <label for="fm-tool_table_size">* Table Size:</label>
  <select id="fm-tool_table_size" name="fm-tool_table_size">
    <option value="All" selected="selected">All Table Sizes</option>
    <option value="1ft">1 foot</option>
    <option value="3ft">3 foot</option>
    <option value="6ft">6 foot</option>
  </select>

  <label for="fm-tool_file">* Tool File:</label>
  <input id="fm-tool_file" name="fm-tool_file" type="file" />
  <label for="fm-tool_image">* Tool Image:</label>
  <input id="fm-tool_image" name="fm-tool_image" type="file" />
</fieldset>

<div id="sub">
  <input id="upload_tool" name="upload_tool" value="Submit tool" type="submit" />
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
function validate()
{
   if( document.getElementById('fm-username').value == "" || document.getElementById('fm-username').length < 4 || document.getElementById('fm-username').value > 20){
     alert( "The username should be between 4 and 20 characters!" );
     document.getElementById('fm-username').focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   var str=document.getElementById('fm-email').value;
   var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
   if (!filter.test(str)) {
     alert( "This is not a valid email format" );
     document.getElementById('fm-email').focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   var str=document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').value;
   var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;
   if (str.search(regexp) == -1){
     alert( "Only alpha numeric values and _ or - are allowed in the tool name" );
     document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   if( document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').value == "" || document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').length < 4 || document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').value > 30){
     alert( "The Tool name should be between 4 and 30 characters" );
     document.getElementById('fm-tool_name').focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   if( document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').value == "" || document.getElementById('fm-fm-tool_desc').length < 4 || document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').value > 30){
     alert( "The Description should be between 4 and 65,000 characters" );
     document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   var file_value = document.getElementById("fm-tool_image").value;
   alert("fup "+ file_value);

    var ext = file_value.substring(file_value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    alert("ext "+ ext);

    if(ext == "gif" || ext == "GIF" || ext == "JPEG" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "JPG" || ext == "png")
    {
    alert("looks good");
    } else{
    return false;
    }


   return(true);

}
```

And the css

```
form {
    margin : 0 auto;
    text-align : center;
    width : 450px;
    font-size : 1.2em;
    font : 85.5%/1.5 arial, verdana, helvetica, tahoma, sans-serif;
}

form p {
    text-align : left;
    margin : 0.5em 0;
}

fieldset, #sub {
    margin : 1em 0;
    padding : 0 1em .5em;
    border : 0 none;
    border-top : #cccccc 1px solid;
}

#sub {
    border : 0 none;
}

legend {
    margin : 1em;
    padding : 0 1.5em;
    color : #003366;
    background : transparent;
    font-size : 1.1em;
    font-weight : bold;
}

legend.p {
    text-align : left;
    margin : 0.5em 0;
    padding : 0;
    color : #333333;
    font-size : 1.2em;
    font-weight : normal;
}

label {
    float : left;
    width : 110px;
    padding : 0 1em;
    text-align : right;
}

fieldset input, textarea, select {
    width : 250px;
    border-top : #555555 1px solid;
    border-left : #555555 1px solid;
    border-bottom : #cccccc 1px solid;
    border-right : #cccccc 1px solid;
    padding : 1px;
    color : #333333;
    margin-bottom : 0.5em;
}

.fm-multi {
    margin : 5px 0;
    border : 0 none;
    width : 100%;
}

.fm-multi input {
    width : auto;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    border : 0 none;
}

.fm-multi label {
    display : block;
    width : 200px;
    padding-left : 5em;
    text-align : left;
    margin : 0 auto 0.5em;
}

#fm-submit {
    clear : both;
    text-align : center;
    border : #333333 1px solid;
    padding : 1px;
    background : #555555;
    color : #ffffff;
    width : 7em;
    margin : 1em auto;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background : #efefef;
    color : #000000;
}

fieldset .fm-req {
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line of your code and then single step through the function to find the error. If there are any errors within your validate function then the page will be submitted. This is the default behaviour for all browsers.

Comment: did you get the alert "looks good" when you enter bad value too?

Comment: Note: return is not a method so `return(true);` should be `return true;`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSFiddle is set to run the code onload so the function you are trying to call is not in global scope. The browser throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined` and submits.

Change how the fiddle loads the JavaScript with the select method, put the code into the head.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be this:

```
if(document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').value == "" || document.getElementById('fm-fm-tool_desc').length < 4 || document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').value > 30){
     alert( "The Description should be between 4 and 65,000 characters" );
     document.getElementById('fm-tool_desc').focus() ;
     return false;
}
```

The ID `fm-fm-tool_desc` doesn't exist. My console gives me a `TypeError` saying `null is not an object`.

Change this to `fm-tool_desc` and it should go fine.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTV5p/8/)

**Please note**

I have changed `function validate()` to `validate=function()` and added a semicolon at the very end of your function definition.

**Hint**

Your file extension comparison condition is rather intense. You don't need to compare lower and uppercase separately. You can use `ext.toLowerCase()=='gif'` instead (`.toLowerCase()` will give you the string in lower case).